# Increasing a 32T chainring to a 36T - will it fit?

Tags: chainring, compatibility, preventative-maintenance

I'm considering changing up the chainring on this 2020 Specialized Turbo Levo Comp in order to slow down wear on the cassette as the rider tends to keep it in a few of the mid-high gears.

What practical considerations (beyond BCD and chainlength) are there for increasing the size up from 32 to say 36T? How far could one go? I'm going to swap the chain and cassette and am considering swapping the chainring too at this opportunity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Complementary question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/87688/does-changing-a-chainring-on-a-e-bike-requires-a-firmware-change-setting-or

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting [this website](https://support.specialized.com/turbolevo/en/previous-generations/2019-2021-turbo-levo/2019-2021-turbo-levo-features-benefits-range#id-20192021TurboLevoFeatures,Benefits,&Range-Drivetrain) from Specialized:

> All models use a 12 speed drivetrain with a single front chainring. 32t minimum and 34t maximum (with chainguide) or 36t maximum (without chainguide)

You've already covered most of the important practical considerations. Another minor effect is that chainring size is linked to suspension performance. The exact relationship will depend on the specific bike's suspension geometry, but generally, a larger chainring will result in reduced anti-squat. Your bike may bob up and down somewhat more when pedaling.

Comment: Nice nice, thank you, don't think I would have found that link

Still, fair play to Spesh for the content/support

Comment: @Swifty My pleasure! Specialized is generally pretty good with documentation, yup.

Answer (score 5):

**Maybe.**   Your cheap option is to print one and hold it up, see if it fits.

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0230/9291/files/Chainring_ToothCount_Guide_0bafabd2-d82f-436e-be92-8c479a0f32b1.pdf
is an excellent tool for this purpose.  Just make sure your printer is at 100% and the ruler measures right.